# JAVA: generic type class inheritance and generic type inheritance

Tags: java, generic-type-argument

let me state my situation first:

I've, in a 3rd party SDK, a base class with generic type:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseDataType> {
    public abstract class BaseDataType {xxx}
    public abstract int getCount();
    public abstract someMethod(T t);
}
```

in my business environment, it extends `BaseClass` as follows:

```
public abstract class MyGeneralBaseClas<`how to write this???`> extends BaseClass {
    @Override public int getCount() {return some_list.size()};
    @Override public abstract someMethod(`how to write this???`);
}
```

in the real business, I write my class:

```
public class MyClass extends MyGeneralBaseClass<MyDataType> {
    @Override public someMethod(MyDataType type) {xxx}
}

public class MyDataType extends BaseClass.BaseDataType {
    xxx
}
```

but the code failed to compile. sorry I'm travelling and I don't have my IDE and development tools, so I cannot paste the error. but I think if you write this down in an IDE such IntelliJ Idea, it would give the error I'm encountering.

so how to write this case: inheritance of generic type, and inheritance of the class using the generic type.

what i want is, in `MyClass` uses the concrete class `MyDataType` instead of the abstract `BaseDataType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `MyGeneralBaseClas` should have a generic type parameter with the same type bound as `BaseClass`:

```
public abstract class MyGeneralBaseClas<T extends BaseDataType> extends BaseClass<T> {
    @Override public int getCount() {return some_list.size()};
    @Override public abstract someMethod(T t);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want. would you plz do me a favor to explain in detail? or provide some easy-to-understand article URL. many thx

Comment: @McArthorLee Based on `class MyClass extends MyGeneralBaseClass<MyDataType>` I figured you wanted `MyGeneralBaseClas` to have a generic type parameter that extends `BaseDataType`. Therefore `MyGeneralBaseClas<T extends BaseDataType>`. Now, since `BaseClass` also requires a type parameter that extends `BaseDataType`, use can pass `T` to it, which gives you `class MyGeneralBaseClas<T extends BaseDataType> extends BaseClass<T>`

Comment: yes, you are right. but your explaination is about my business environment. could you give some generic JAVA explainations. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. By using `BaseDataType` class as is, e.g.:

   ```
   abstract class MyGeneralBaseClas<T extends BaseDataType> extends BaseClass<T> {
       @Override public void someMethod(T t){}
   }
   ```
2. By extending `BaseDataType` class, e.g.:

   ```
   class DerivedDataType extends BaseDataType{
       //Some code
   }

   abstract class MyAnotherBAseClass<DerivedDataType> extends BaseClass{
       @Override
       public void someMethod(com.gamesys.application.BaseDataType t) {}
   }
   ```

Comment: when i extends `BaseDataType`, it means i'm at the business environment, so i must define a concrete class instead of an abstract one.